# Columns Order In Datagridview With ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net

What is the correct way of **datagridviewcomboboxcolumn** bind with sql database and re-
arrange with other column. Suppose if I have columns like below.

1. Srno
2. Particulars   // this columns is for datagridviewcomboBoxColumn
3. Amount.

I wants  the datagridview’s columns correct order as above and the same is for the purpose

of data entry.

Suppose if I have Following Dummy Table like

**dummy**

1. **Srno**
2. **Particulars**
3. **Amount.**

MySqlConnection Code is as below.

```
string cons = "server=.;initial catalog=maa;uid=mah;pwd=mah";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cons);
con.Open();
string sql = "select particulars from dummy";
SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dap.Fill(ds);
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cmb.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
cmb.DisplayMember = "name";
cmb.ValueMember = "name";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);
```

**The above datagridviewcomboboxcolumn  is set  to dgv.columns[0] where as  I wants the dgv**

**columns orders as below.**

1. Datagridview.columns[0]   is for srno
2. Datagridview.columns[1]   is for Particulars
3. Datagridview.columns[2]   is for Amount

**Note:- "I need the correct way to add all three columns in datagridview as above order"**

Comment: I don't understand your issue.

Comment: @ykatchou, Read the comment below Slaks's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`DisplayIndex` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex.aspx) of the columns.

Comment: @Slaks, Thanks but it is part solution. How can I add all three columns in DGV. I know how to bind dgvcomboBoxColumn but the issue is how to prepare dgv with all three columns.

Comment: ... the other column like "srno,amount" how to add in DGV. it can possible by datatable and dataset. but it looks like part by sql and part by datatable. I am confused How to put three columns together in right way. as above suggested order.

Comment: @Slaks, Yah! it's true but for that i have to declare datatable and dataset. Can You give me some example in right way.

Comment: @mahesh: No, you don't need to use a DataTable.  You can just add an unbound column by calling `Columns.Add`.

Comment: @Slaks, How? is your mean like "datagridview1.Columns.Add()"

Comment: @Slaks Yes the error is "The best overloaded method match for System.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.add". See i am trying like this " datagridview1.Columns.Add("srno") and it's throw  the error same.

Comment: Did you look at the function's parameters?

Comment: @Slaks, I have no idea about it.

Comment: Then why don't you look at the function? (In MSDN)

Comment: @Slaks, I don't think that function parameters will solve the issue particulars in case of above. if you think so then present your way

Comment: @mahesh: `dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Srno", "Srno")`

Comment: @Slaks, yeah! it's works but there is little problem we can't set it with index, i mean how to set at "columns[0]"

Comment: Set the `DisplayIndex` property of the new column, as I just said.

Comment: @Slaks, agreed with you and ready to accept you but I require your opinion against my new suggestion if you allow than i will put front of you by new answer.